# flask sign/unsign verify usage in nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, flask, cookies

In python, there is this usage of flask that can verify if a cookie is signed with a given key.

```
flask_unsign import session
session_cookie = "eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiY2Q3Y2FiMzBjOTE2NTM5ZjFhMDViYTY2NmVlY2VkNTgzZjYzYzg0MSIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuIn0.ZE6ojQ.xpmHBDQeY28iOgZwFtbe-GJOLLE"
verified = session.verify(session_cookie, b'Change_me')
if verified:
  #here it is verified
```

I want to convert this same to Node.js, yet I fail. I tried this:

```
var theSessValue = "eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiY2Q3Y2FiMzBjOTE2NTM5ZjFhMDViYTY2NmVlY2VkNTgzZjYzYzg0MSIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuIn0.ZE6ojQ.xpmHBDQeY28iOgZwFtbe-GJOLLE";
    
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const base64url = require('base64url');
console.log("Parser: " + cookieParser.signedCookie(theSessValue, "Change_me"); //returns eyJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiY2Q3Y2FiMzBjOTE2NTM5ZjFhMDViYTY2NmVlY2VkNTgzZjYzYzg0MSIsImxvY2FsZSI6ImVuIn0.ZE6ojQ.xpmHBDQeY28iOgZwFtbe-GJOLLE

//const decodedSessionData = base64url.decode(theSessValue);
//const decodedSessionData = Buffer.from(theSessValue, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
//console.log(decodedSessionData);
```

Yet this fails, it keeps logging theSessValue which is the value passed to the parameter, which means it is "If the value was not signed, the original value is returned" from  [express js](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cookie-parser.html)

ok but, is there an equivalent of `session.verify()` from flask for nodejs ?